# Addition with substituted numbers

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

Spending quite some time on setting $A=8$ and $G=9$, it took me quite a while to figure out that can't be true. Is there a faster/better way to solve this, or is it just trial and error? It's quite easy to miss some cases trying all possible digits.

Comment: One point is that the sum of all the digits in the problem is $0 \bmod 9$.  We also have $A+B+C+D+E+F\equiv G+H+I \bmod 9$.  That gives $GHI$ is divisible by $9$, which reduces the search space.

Comment: Also, wlog $C<E<F$ and $B<D$

Comment: @RossMillikan: You gave me the right idea to use modular arithmetic, but mod $2$ turned out to be even more useful than mod $9$.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of all digits is odd, so there must be an odd number of carries to make the sum come out right. Since $A\ne G$ there must be a carry from the tens to the hundreds, so there’s no carry from the ones to the tens. If $A=8$ and $G=9$, that leaves only the options $I=6$ or $I=7$, with $CEF=123$ in the first case and $CEF=124$ in the second case. (As Hagen commented, the order of $CEF$ doesn’t matter.) The remaining digits are $457$ in the first case and $356$ in the second case, neither of which works in the tens column. Thus $A=8$ and $G=9$ is impossible. The next-highest option is $A=7$ and $G=8$, leaving $I=6$ or $I=9$. A lower sum in the ones leads to a higher sum overall, so if $I=6$ works we’re done. And indeed this implies $CEF=123$, leaving $459$ for the tens column, which works if we add $5+9=14$ with a carry. Thus the highest possible sum is $846$, and one possible assignment is

```
 751
  92
+  3
 ---
 846.
```

P.S.: We also need to exclude the possibility that there are two carries in the ones (and thus an odd number of three carries in total). This can’t happen if $A=8$ and $G=9$, since $5+6+7\lt21$. It can’t happen if $A=7$ and $G=8$, either, since $5+6+9\lt21$, and anyway a greater sum in the ones would lead to a lesser sum overall.